# Ubuntu 16.10 kernel version vs linux-headers-generic version

Tags: kernel, updates

On my Ubuntu Server 16.10, `uname -a` lists `4.8.0-17-generic` as the kernel version. This is in fact the version listed in all files in the `/boot` directory.

But I no longer have the package `linux-headers-generic` with version `4.8.0-17` installed. It has been updated by `apt upgrade` to version `4.8.0-30`.

Is this normal? Should I be concerned about the mismatch?

Comment: It sounds like your update process has been loading the newer kernels, but you have not been booting into them.  I would load a GUI grub editor, like [Grub-Cusomizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) and check to see what version of Ubuntu you are booting by default.

Comment: Did you reboot since the last kernel update? If not, please do that and check again.